# Copying database table to another with additional field?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have two table. I want to copy table1 to table2 including schema and data. Their structure are as follows. Table2 has the same structure with table1 except that table2 has additional field. Total field of table1 are up to 500. So I think it is not a good way to write down every field name.
Is there good way to do this? 
Thank you in advance.

table1(
  node1, 
  node2, 
  node3 ... 
  node500
  )

table2(
  code_name, 
  code_date, 
  node1, 
  node2, 
  node3 ... 
  node500
  )

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT...SELECT... form of the [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) accepts any query, so you can just construct a query that results in the data you want. So in this case, you can use `*` to get all columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT 'new name', 'new date', * FROM table2;
```

Comment: Thank you CL. However what I want is to copy table1 into table2 and add two column.

Comment: That's what this statement does.